# Vue parent/child methods best practice

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I am trying to figure out the best way to build a modal component, it needs to have hide and show methods which can be called either from the parent or from the component itself.

1. Store the status on the child. Use ref on the child component and have the parent call a method on the child which updates the status and shows/hides the component.
2. Store the status on the parent and pass it to the child as a prop. Use emit to communicate the change in status to the parent when the child needs to hide itself.

which would be the best way to do this?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please elaborate what are you trying to achieve. The way you handle a modal depends on your app structure

Answer (score 1):

I think, use `$emit` on child and store status on parent.

It's probably different depending on the lens.
With this method, you don't have a problem with refreshing the child component.